# How to allocate a event function to DOM list in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

I would like to ask you about using  a event function in React.js.

I want to make test function,  which would get index and print index when  of titlesList is clicked. 
But this function doesn't work when  is clicked.

Could you give me advices to solve it?

```
const some = (props) = {
    // 'props' have two attributes, titles and contents
    // which each is a array of strings.



    function test(index){
        console.log('clicked');
        console.log(index);
     }

    const titlesList = props.titles.map((title, index) => {

        return <div className="eachTitle"
            key={index}
            onClick={test(index)}>
            {title} {index}
        </div>
    });

    return (
            <div>
                    {titlesList}
            </div>
    );
}
```

Thank you for reading.

Comment: try onClick = {() =>test(index)}

Comment: you should mark Jtcruthers answer as correct, as he took the time to actually answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your component is rendered, it will actually call `test(index)`. This sets the value of `onClick` to the return value of `test(index)`. What you'll want to do is set onClick to a function that calls whatever you want with the proper arguments.

`onClick={() => {test(index)}}`

This is an anonymous function, which can be passed around. When clicked, the anonymous function is called, which really just calls `test(index)` with your arguments. If you didn't need to pass any argument to `test`, you could have just done:

`onClick={test}`.

Since you can't tell onClick to pass arguments (besides the event object), the anonymous function is an easy way to get around that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your effort!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is with the binding, there are two approach to resolve it,  one mentioned by @Jtcruthers using anonymous function and another way is to create a constructor and register you method using `.bind()` while calling use this

```
onClick={this.test(index)}
```

```
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.test = this.test.bind(this);
}
```

```
    function test(index){
        console.log('clicked');
        console.log(index);
     }

     const titlesList = props.titles.map((title, index) => {

        return <div className="eachTitle"
            key={index}
            onClick={this.test(index)}>
            {title} {index}
        </div>
    });
```

Comment: Thank for your explanation.